# way to achieve consistency and availability in CAP theorem

Tags: database, distributed-computing

### how can we achieve consistency and availability in better way ?

Hey can any one explain how can I achieve Consistency as well as Availability together while partition tolerance exists?

Comment: Not a question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The CAP Theorem states that you can't. What you can do, though, is achieve [Eventual Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). It is quite a lot of work, though. Another keyword for searching is Idempotent Messages.